# Make my textbox view result from a LINQ query

Tags: database, linq, textbox

Hi guys im trying to make my textbox to view names on each item i click on my dropdownbox. So I would like to match the result with the dropdown and then display it in the textbox.

I have done this and it seems not working.

```
            var sql = (from query in dwe.VW_CustumAddress
                       where query.Postal == DropDownListPostal.SelectedItem.ToString()
                       select query);

            if (sql != null)
            {
                NavnBox.Text = data.Name;
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to debug this one.

```
var selectedItem = DropDownListPostal.SelectedItem;
if (selectedItem != null) {
   var postal = selectedItem.ToString();//check if it looks like something you want
   var data = dwe.VW_CustumAddress.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Postal == postal);
   if (data != null)
      NavnBox.Text = data.Name;
}
```